# Creating a cookie if it doesn't exist inside of my Action that I created with ActionBuilder

Tags: scala, playframework

I have a Action builder that looks like:

```
case class User(id: Int, name: String)

class MyObject[A](val user: User, request: Request[a]) extends WrappedRequest[a](request)
```

My custom action looks like:

```
object MyAction extends ActionBuilder[MyObject] {
    def invokeBlock[a](request: Request[a], block: (MyObject[a]) => Future[SimpleResult]) = {

    // lookup cookie if it exists
    val cookie = request.cookies.get("mycookie")

    // if the cookie doesn't exist, I want to create a cookie  ???????????
    block(new MyObject(user, request))
  }
}
```

So inside my action I want to somehow create a cookie if it doesn't exist.

How can I do this?

Also, under certain conditions, I would also want to redirect to another page.   Is this possible also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a cookie in the response.

```
def invokeBlock[a](request: Request[a], block: (MyObject[a]) => Future[SimpleResult]) = {
  val result: Future[SimpleResult] = block(new MyObject(user, request))
  redirectUri().fold(cookie.fold(result.map(_.withCookies(Cookie(....))(futureResult => futureResult) { someRedirectUri =>
     Future.successful(Results.redirect(someRedirectUri))
  }
}

def redirectUri(): Option[String] = {
   //Your logic here to determine if redirect is needed
   ....

}
```

Comment: thanks, can you explain what the redirectUri().fold and cookie.fold and result.map are doing?  A little confuses still.

Comment: This is the definition of `fold` in `Option` in Scala Doc: `final def fold[B](ifEmpty: ⇒ B)(f: (A) ⇒ B): B`.   Returns the result of applying `f` to this scala.Option's value if the scala.Option is nonempty. Otherwise, evaluates expression `ifEmpty`.